# Setting Locale using Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I'm getting following error while trying to set locale inside the container using Docker-file:

Followed several posts(eg: jaredmarkell.com/docker-and-locales) but not  succeeded

```
Baseimage info: Linux version 3.10 (Red Hat 4.8.5)

Dockerfile: 

# set locale to utf-8

RUN yum -y reinstall glibc-common

RUN localedef -v -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8

ENV LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

Also tried with RUN localedef -quiet -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8


**Error:** /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:8: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:9: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:11: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:14: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:15: non-symbolic character value should not be used /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:16: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:17: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:19: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:20: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:21: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:22: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:23: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:24: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:25: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:26: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:27: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:28: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:29: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:34: non-symbolic character value should not be used

[0m[91m/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:50: non-symbolic character value should not be used

[0m[91m/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n:1425: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n:1674: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n:1719: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n:1756: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:53: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:59: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:152: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:40: non-symbolic character value should not be used

[0m[91m/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1:3: non-symbolic character value should not be used

[0m[91m/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:10: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:11: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:12: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:13: non-symbolic character value should not be used

[0m[91m/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:14: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:15: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:16: non-symbolic character value should not be used

/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:17: non-symbolic character value should not be used

[0m[91mLC_NAME: field `name_gen' not defined

LC_IDENTIFICATION: field `audience' not defined

LC_IDENTIFICATION: field `application' not defined

LC_IDENTIFICATION: field `abbreviation' not defined

LC_IDENTIFICATION: no identification for category `LC_MEASUREMENT'

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for class "upper": 1756 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for class "lower": 1756 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for class "alpha": 4320 bytes

LC_CTYPE: table for class "digit": 600 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for class "xdigit": 600 bytes

LC_CTYPE: table for class "space": 856 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for class "print": 5976 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for class "graph": 5976 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for class "blank": 856 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for class "cntrl": 664 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for class "punct": 4824 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for class "alnum": 4320 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for class "combining": 3152 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for class "combining_level3": 2832 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for map "toupper": 16924 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for map "tolower": 15388 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for map "totitle": 16924 bytes

[0m[91mLC_CTYPE: table for width: 26712 bytes
```

Comment: Can you please give us the whole Dockerfile, especially the FROM part?

Comment: Hey!  my base image is a customized one

Comment: It seems like `localedef` is used to compile locale definition files, which means you compile a charmapfile from an inputfile.

It may be the wrong command for just _setting_ a preexisting locale.

Isn't the `ENV LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` instruction enough to set the locale?